# Where can I find a comprehensive list of UI Components?

Tags: design-patterns, component, library

I think this is the site where I can ask this.

Sometimes I have to build specials "slider" or "scrollbar" but when I try to look for information is difficult because I don't know the proper names.

And when I receive the design it is not very clear.

**update**

I realize that as @Anna Rouben has mentioned, components can be named different through platforms, so I especially need it for web

Comment: There is no comprehensive list.

Comment: Fair enough, could we say the most complete list?

Comment: There is no standards governing body when it comes to UI nomenclature. There's common terms that we've all gotten used to over the years, but the only terms that really matter are the terms your teams are using. I'd suggest that your team and the team handing you the designs start collaborating on your own internal UI component library. That way everyone will be on the same page when it comes to the terms being used.

Comment: I see your point, thanks DA01. But as long as on web we used popular libraries I think should be at least a very common terms for a bunch of component, am I right? I don't think we differ terms so much.

Answer (score 5):

For the web: http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/

Yahoo!'s Pattern library also gives you some general tips about when to use what and why.

Comment: I know its from 2012, but the link goes to a 404 page ;)

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of a single place where you can look up ui components for any platform. Similar components are sometimes called differently based on a platform. Therefore it might be helpful to refer to the UX documentations for a specific platform:

Android
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html

Windows 8
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465424

Comment: What about web UI Components? do you have any links about it? I forgot to mention that,

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple more sources of interaction design patterns that include UI components:

[Welie](http://www.welie.com/patterns/index.php)

[Designing Interfaces](http://designinginterfaces.com/patterns/)

Answer (score 0):

[Quince](http://quince.infragistics.com/#/Search) is a great resource for UI elements and usage patterns. It is rather extensive and provides examples on when certain controls or elemtents are more appropriate than others and why.

Comment: This website is shut down, as of 2018 and per their homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Another good example — [Semantic UI](https://semantic-ui.com/globals/site.html). It has a clear structure, all the element states and the code as well.

Comment: One line link answers are often deleted at UXSE, even though you might have the correct answer. URLs often change and links get broken so it's better to provide a quote of the most important content to answer the question.